# Does Nancy on Owin have any built in size limit for query string?

Tags: owin, nancy

We're having a strange experience with our Nancy/Owin hosted api - when the URL query string is longer than 255 characters Nancy returns a 400 Bad Request.

Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it turns out the problem was caused by our URL being non-standard.

The URL was in the format `http://www.blah.com/something=blah&something2=blah`

Something in the Nancy/Owin pipeline was (correctly) treating this string as the url path and not the query string, and apparently this thing cannot be larger than 255 characters.

As soon as we introduced standard query string formatting (with a '?') this resolved the issue.

Got help from:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28782/why-do-i-get-an-error-400-with-one-constructed-url-and-not-with-the-other-one

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16996/maximum-domain-name-length